# Redux not causing re-render after deep cloning the original state, mutating it, then returning it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a redux slice as following:

```
export const mealPlanSlice = createSlice({
  name: "mealPlanner",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addOrUpdatePlan: addOrUpdate,
  }
})

export const { addOrUpdatePlan } = mealPlanSlice.actions;

export default mealPlanSlice.reducer;
```

With a reducer that I am embarrassed to show below (personal project no judging pls). The logic is correct but I am not getting re-renders when the action is dispatched. Redux dev tools shows the correct difference. I thought that by deep-cloning the previous state, mutating that state, and then returning it would be guaranteed I get a re-render after running but apparently not. I am quite confused at this point because I have manually checked that each level has been deep-cloned correctly and fail a shallow equality check with the previous value.

Would someone be able to explain what is going wrong please? I am having this problem with other slices for my project as well, so there must be some underlying issue I am not seeing.

```
import clone from "just-clone";

export const addOrUpdate = (
  state: IMealPlanState,
  action: PayloadAction<
    { date: DateString } & {
      components: {
        recipeId: RecipeUuid;
        componentId: ComponentUuid;
        servingsIncrease: number;
      }[];
    }
  >
) => {
  const newState = clone(state);

  const { date, components } = action.payload;
  for (const { recipeId, componentId, servingsIncrease } of components) {
    if (newState.plan[date]) {
      if (recipeId in newState.plan[date]) {
        const componentIndex = newState.plan[date][recipeId].findIndex(
          (mealPlanItem) => mealPlanItem.componentId === componentId
        );
        if (componentIndex > -1) {
          const component = newState.plan[date][recipeId][componentIndex];
          const newServings = component.servings + servingsIncrease;
          if (newServings > 0) {
            newState.plan[date][recipeId][componentIndex].servings =
              newServings;
          } else {
            newState.plan[date][recipeId].splice(componentIndex, 1);
            if (newState.plan[date][recipeId].length === 0) {
              delete newState.plan[date][recipeId];
            }
          }
        } else {
          newState.plan[date][recipeId].push({
            componentId,
            servings: servingsIncrease,
          });
        }
      } else {
        newState.plan[date][recipeId] = [
          {
            componentId,
            servings: servingsIncrease,
          },
        ];
      }
    }
  }

  return newState;
};
```

For context my store looks like the following

```
export const store = configureStore<IFullStoreState>({
  reducer: {
    printing,
    plants,
    food,
    mealPlan,
    user,
  },
});
```

For extra context my component that subscribes to this slice looks a bit like

```
const Recipes = () => {
  const mealPlan = useSelector((store) => store.mealPlan.plan);

  return ...
}
```

On further investigation this only happens in a development build, after making a deployment the problem disappears. I am using NextJS.

Comment: I don't see `mealPlan` being mutated anywhere here.  Suggestion: start with shallow values and make sure that's working for you before trying to debug this over-complex reducer you've got.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the exports for the slice, `mealPlan` in the store is the default export from the slice. In the reducer, `state` is `mealPlan`, there are a few places where I reference `plan` from `state`. If that makes sense.